# how to upload user image in my websrvice

Tags: java, android, json

Sir 
i want add user_image in webservice through the Signup activity i m using json 
here is my Signup Acitivity
Signup.java

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static String url = "http://www.mydomain.com/signup";


//Go To Login.java  
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bktologin); 
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }); 
// Close Login.java
    // button to add image
    viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    selectpic=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnphoto);
    selectpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            selectImage();
        }
    });
}
    private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Signin.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions); 

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }





//Get all data and log in 
        signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.register); 
        fullName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        userName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);
        age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
        viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        gender=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.gndr);
        interestIn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.intrst);
        toMeet=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tomeet);

    /*image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);*/
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

    //Check all fields      

             if(pwd.length()<4)
            {               
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this,"Please Enter minimum 4 letters in password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

    //check connectivity        
             if(!isOnline(Signin.this))
            {                   
                Toast.makeText(Signin.this,"No network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return; 
            }

    //from login.java       
                new loginAccess().execute();
        }

    //code to check online details
    private boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
      {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
  //Close code that check online details        
  }); 
    //Close log in 
}


class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Signin.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Sig in...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String FullName=fullName.getText().toString();
    String UserName=userName.getText().toString();
    String DateOfBirth=dob.getText().toString();
    String Age=age.getText().toString();


    String Sex=gender.getText().toString();
    String InterestedIn=interestIn.getText().toString();
    String ToMeet=toMeet.getText().toString();


    String strimg = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytearr, 0, bytearr.length, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String Email=email.getText().toString();
    String Password=pwd.getText().toString();



    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullName", FullName));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", UserName));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", DateOfBirth));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", Age));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", Sex));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("interestIn", InterestedIn));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("toMeet", ToMeet));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", strimg));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", Password));




    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);

    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    try {

        if (json.has((TAG_SUCCESS))) {
            String status = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (status.equals("Success")) 
         {
          flag=0;   
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
    /*i.putExtra("Email",email);
          i.putExtra("Password", pwd);*/
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
         }
         else
         {
            // failed to Sign in
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if(flag==1)
        Toast.makeText(Signin.this,"Please Enter Correct informations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of sending image in form of string send it as byte array.
ie. While sending convet Bitmap image to byte array and send and while receiving get the byte array and convert it to Bitmap image.